# Reformatting a string and placing parts of it in separate variables

Tags: ios, swift, string, uicolor

I'm trying to format a string that is entered by a user, and then want to place parts of that string in three separate variables.

```
//This is the text the user enters
rgbInputTextField.text == "253, 254, 255" //(Or variations like "53 54 55" or "3,4,5")


//I'd like to place that string in three variables such that:
R == 253
G == 254
G == 255
```

Am I approaching this completely wrong? The goal is to register the RGB input string from the user and convert it to a Hex value.

I'm able to convert to Hex once I have the R, G and B variables, but can't figure out how to place the rgbInputTextField String into those three separate variables. I've found many UIColor extensions that can convert a hex string to UIColor, but nothing that converts an rgb string (with variations) to hex/UIColor.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the numbers of the string using:

```
let string = "122, 255, 2"
var array = String(stringLiteral: string).components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
array = array.filter { $0 != "" }
```

Resulting on: `["122", "255", "2"]`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find a way to parse the string and after each comma, store the variable of R, G, and B. For this, you could create a regular expression using NSRegularExpression.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression

If I were you, I would just make three separate textFields and read in values from the inputs.

Comment: I think the last part of this answer is the best solution, both for OP and the user